Memory leaks with CToolTipCtrl
I wrote:
void CDoDlg::InizializzaToolTip(void)
{
    CString strToolTip;         ///< Stringa da mostrare.

    if (m_ToolTip1.Create(this) == FALSE)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(strToolTip, MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    else
    {
        m_bTTIniz = true;
        
        strToolTip.LoadString(IDS_STRING119);   //[ITA] Click per aprire una nuova fustella.
        m_ToolTip1.AddTool(&m_button, strToolTip);
        m_ToolTip1.Activate(TRUE);
    }
}

BOOL CDoDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (m_bClose == false)
    {
            m_ToolTip1.RelayEvent(pMsg);
    
    }
    return CDialogEx::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}

And then:
CDoDlg::~CDoDlg()
{
    if (m_pArt)
        delete m_pArt;

    if (m_pImageList)
        m_pImageList->DeleteImageList();

      m_ToolTip1.DestroyWindow();   
}

And I have memory leaks and I don't know how I can solve it:

Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {25320} normal block at 0x0FD24F48, 26 bytes long.
 Data: < %mP            > B0 25 6D 50 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\plex.cpp(29) : {25319} normal block at 0x0FDE9978, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <             $5b> 00 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD 00 00 00 00 A5 24 35 62



Please edit the question and include [mcve]

This is the 25320th allocation. You must have operated the application for some time already.

yes, but I don't know why tooltip create memory leaks

Do you still get the memory leak if you remove the tooltip altogether? Also check if m_ToolTip1.DestroyWindow()  succeeds.

Memory leak detection operates on the CRT heap alone. Controls do not use the CRT for memory they manage. The issue is somewhere in your code. m_bClose (and the special handling it controls) is likely part of the issue.

why 'code' m_bClose?
